# Default enter and space key behavior wpf applications

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, default, space, enter

I'm trying to put together a small application in WPF (a media player) using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop, and want to use the space bar to pause.  Unfortunately, the space bar, as well as the enter key, seem to have a default behavior in which (just before they execute any commands I have programmed for them) they re-execute or re-raise the most recent event in the window (button clicks, keypresses, etc.).

I have tried overriding OnKeydown, OnKeyUp, OnPreviewKeyDown, and OnPreviewKeyUp in every combination, but no amount of overriding eliminates this behavior.  I have also found that this is true in other WPF applications I wrote, and even in a Windows Forms application I put together a few months ago.  Is this some default aspect of all applications built by Visual Studio?  And more importantly, is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override `OnPreviewKeyDown` you can add the logic you want, then set `e.Handled` to `true` and this will prevent the event from bubbling up and causing the behavior you are seeing.

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        //Your Logic
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```